# Altair python: solid horizontal bars in the backgound

Tags: python, altair

I'd like to do something like this in altair

[image: what I want]

What I have accomplished so far is the following, and I can't figure out how to paint the background as I need

[image: what I have]

```
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='Year',
    y='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)'
)

band0 = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y': [20]})).mark_rule(color='red').encode(y='y')
band1 = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y': [30]})).mark_rule(color='orange').encode(y='y')

line + band0 + band1
```

Thanks in advance!
Lorena

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shade a region with Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482055/how-to-shade-a-region-with-altair)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via `mark_rect` and a `y2` encoding [as per this gallery example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/falkensee.html) and [How to shade a region with Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482055/how-to-shade-a-region-with-altair).

```
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

source = data.cars()
line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='Year',
    y='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)')

band0 = (alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y': [0], 'y2':[30]}))
         .mark_rect(color='red', opacity=0.3)
         .encode(y='y', y2='y2'))
band1 = (alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y': [20], 'y2':[35]}))
         .mark_rect(color='yellow', opacity=0.3)
         .encode(y='y', y2='y2'))

line + band0 + band1
```

[image]